# K8 Lens is not detecting Kubernetes information

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've installed K8Lens 6.0.1 version on Mac Monterey and getting ***Unknown Error Occurred*** while connecting to AWS EKS through it. I tried installing the 5.x version, but got an ***Invalid Credentials*** error. I'm able to access AWS EKS through CLI with the same credentials (AWS SSO). One more thing to mention here is Lens is not detecting the Kubelet version and Kubernetes Distribution in the ***View Details*** tab of the EKS cluster but not sure if this could be the reason. I tried resetting credentials and clearing the app cache as well but it didn't work.
Kubectl Client version is 1.24 and Server version is 1.22+.
Thanks.